# Moq Unit Test disappear after solving badimageformatexception

Tags: c#, asp.net, moq, platform, badimageformatexception

So I had this problem : [badimageformatexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35063399/all-unit-tests-throwing-badimageformatexception-with-moq)

I had it once already, and solved it quickly.

But now I pulled a referenced project from Git, and when I match the correct CPU parameters in my test project, in order not to have these Warning messages

> Warning The processor's architecture from 'MyProjet' currently building doesn't match the architecture form the reference 'PulledProject', Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL", "AMD64".

When CPU match, every test disappear in the test launcher. I re-built it, re-added references, cleaned it, I tried a lot of common manipulations, maybe some of you guys and gals have an idea ? It's pretty annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a colleague had the same problem and found this : https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/907

You need to change the architecture of the tests. I did tried before asking here, by changing the properties of my test project and it didn't worked.

But the way described in this link worked for me and my colleague : 
On the menu bar click on Test > Tests Settings > Default Processor Architecture > x64 (or whatever you need).